# rewrite rule to remove /(forward slash) to - (minus)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have given a task to modify a website

I have completed everything but I never work with .htaccess

i want to convert the url (localhost/watch-movies/movie_name/10241) to localhost/watch-movies-movie_name-10241

> I need to change that code
>   RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3

but I don't know what to change?
any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand regex?
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

```
 ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3
```

the  ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+) is the first section before the first /, in your example you left that alone, next there is another group of characters ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+) followed by another forward slash /, then a final group of characters, so you're separating words1/words2/words3. 
You have groups set up also, x equals words1, y is words2, and z is words3.
There must be more code after that puts it back together, you'd want to add all the strings with the appropriate delimeters, so

```
x+"/"+y"-"+z
```

it looks like.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am checking the whole file to find where these are putting together

Comment: actually, it looks like it might be being passed in a URL, the ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 does this get passed to another page?

Comment: You might want to look to see how it is used, perhaps you need to adjust it there. Were you really just looking to change that second "/" into a "-" or is there more to it? Is there going to sometimes be "/"'s in the string itself? Or just the separator?

Comment: Is it possible to z= the value after then - sign

Comment: Have you tried RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_+-\s+]+)$ ?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 ...I changed the / to a -

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35610/discussion-between-mandeep-singh-and-jrafferty)